# Difference between "OFFSET" before/after "FETCH FIRST"

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, syntax

Running the following 2 queries (in postgres) returns the same results, but I see everywhere that method 1 is always preferred.

Are there any difference between the two queries? (Other than syntactic differences).

1)

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
OFFSET 5 ROWS
FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

2)

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY
OFFSET 5 ROWS;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PostgreSQL, there is no difference between the two statements. The SQL:2008 standard, however, places the `offset` clause before the `fetch` clause, so that would be the preferred form, in order to make your code as portable as possible.